# Keyboard is qwerty instead of azerty

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've installed an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop.
This is in a professional environment. We want to avoid all security/performance that Windows can get.
When I connect to my Ubuntu session with my account on our active directory domain, my keyboard is in US or ENG language (ie QWERTY keyboard) where I want it to be french.
When I connect locally, I don't have this issue.
I've checked "region/language" settings as well as $LANG value, everything is France/french.

Can anyone help ?
Serge

Comment: From what operating system in the client computer are you connecting to Ubuntu? Which protocol are you using (ssh or something else)? Which tool are you running in the client?

Comment: If you are connecting from another Ubuntu (computer running Ubuntu) via `ssh` and run a terminal window (for example `gnome-terminal`, you can select keyboard before starting `ssh` or even during the session from another terminal window with the following command, `setxkbmap fr`. With other software there are other ways to set the local keyboard.

Comment: Hi,
my OS is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. 
This is my worstation at work.

Comment: When you connect locally, you don't have this issue. Please explain how you are connecting, when you have this issue. "with my account on our active directory domain" is not enough for me to understand which tools are involved.

Comment: solved: my AD account didn't have the rights to write in /home directory...

Answer (score 1):

my AD account didn't have the rights to write in /home directory...
thanks anyway sudodus

Comment: +1; Thanks for sharing your solution :-)